# replace when found a pattern in multiple lines using sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have to use sed in a shell script to correct a text that is similar to this :

```
>ABC    25  15
>
>FILE   def.exe 3
>INDEX
>
>ABC    12  40
>
>FILE   abc.exe 2
>INDEX
>
>ABC    20  18
>
>FILE   def.exe 5
>INDEX
>
>
```

What I need is to change the "ABC" pattern for "DEF", everytime that the subsequent line show me "FILE  def.exe". Note that between the "ABC" line and the "FILE" line there is a blank line that must remain. At the end of the process, the file must be like this :

```
>DEF    25  15
>
>FILE   def.exe 3
>INDEX
>
>ABC    12  40
>
>FILE   abc.exe 2
>INDEX
>
>DEF    20  18
>
>FILE   def.exe 5
>INDEX
>
>
```

I've tried to use sed with the c option to replace a piece of text, but did not succeed. If anyone has a suggestion, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed  '/^>ABC/{N;N;/FILE[ ]*def.exe/s/>ABC/>DEF/}' input
```

Add the `-i` option to sed if you want to modify the input file.

*Produces:*

```
>DEF    25  15
>
>FILE   def.exe 3
>INDEX
>
>ABC    12  40
>
>FILE   abc.exe 2
>INDEX
>
>DEF    20  18
>
>FILE   def.exe 5
>INDEX
>
>
```

Comment: are we running the same `sed`? Cuz this doesn't work for me.  Ubuntu 13.10, `bash4.2`, `sed4.2`

Comment: @gongzhitaao I believe that perreal was basing the regex on the text shown in the question. You just removed the '>' chars.

Comment: @cosjav Oops, missed that.

Comment: I was about to post an answer that involved reading everything in first, but perreals answer is better :-)

Comment: @gongzhitaao, when we already have the ABC line in the buffer only two N's are needed

Comment: @perreal I was using the `-n` with `p` command, so that three `N`s needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk` (due to record selector)

```
awk '/def.exe/ {sub(/>ABC/,">DEF")} {print $0 RS}' RS="INDEX" file
>DEF    25  15
>
>FILE   def.exe 3
>INDEX

>
>ABC    12  40
>
>FILE   abc.exe 2
>INDEX

>
>DEF    20  18
>
>FILE   def.exe 5
>INDEX

>
>
INDEX
```